# back button not responding for my app in micromax A47

Tags: android, android-button

Back press is not responding for my app on micromax A47 and return a dialog with wait and cancel button. while on other sets its working perfectly al-right.Can you help me with my code or a link to a guide on how to implement this correctly?
Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener{

    boolean             running = true; 
    boolean             isSIM1Ready;
    boolean             isSIM2Ready;

    ProgressWheel       pw_two;
    TelephonyInfo       telephonyInfo;
    Handler             updateBarHandler;
    Context             context;
    Animation           animBlink;  
    int                 progress    =   0;

    private     WebView             wvPlay; 
    private     WebView             wvPlay1;
    private     TextView            tvWait; 
    private     AlertDialog         alert;

    private      DataBaseHandler bdb;

    private  Runnable r ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        pw_two          = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.progressBarTwo);
        pw_two.bringToFront();

        tvWait    =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWait);
        tvWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        wvPlay                      = (WebView)         findViewById(R.id.wvPlay);
        wvPlay.setBackgroundColor(0xffdcffff);
        wvPlay.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/progress.gif");
        wvPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        wvPlay1                      = (WebView)            findViewById(R.id.wv);
        wvPlay1.setBackgroundColor(0xffdcffff);
        wvPlay1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/logo.gif");

        animBlink = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.blink);
        animBlink.setAnimationListener(this);

        telephonyInfo   =     TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);
        isSIM1Ready  =    telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready();
        isSIM2Ready  =    telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready();

        progress = 361;
        pw_two.stopSpinning();
        pw_two.resetCount();

        bdb = new DataBaseHandler(MainActivity.this);

        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        r = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                running = true;
                while(progress<361) {
                    pw_two.incrementProgress();
                    progress++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(15);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                running = false;

                if(running == false){
                    pw_two.startAnimation(animBlink);
                }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("Exception", "******Exception*****" +e);
                }
            }
        };

        mainHandler.post(r);

        pw_two.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Log.e("TAG", "***********");
                    if(!running) {

                         WindowManager manager = (WindowManager)getApplicationContext() .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                         Display mDisplay        = manager.getDefaultDisplay();

                         DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                         manager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

                            switch(displayMetrics.densityDpi)
                            { 
                                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: 
                                    tvWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                break;

                                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                                    tvWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                break;

                                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                                    tvWait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                break;

                                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                                    tvWait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                break;

                                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                                    tvWait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                break;

                             }

                        wvPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progress = 0;
                        pw_two.resetCount();
                        Thread s = new Thread(r);
                        s.start();  
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(300);
                            sendMessage();


                            SimpleDateFormat    dfDate_day1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
                            Calendar            cal1        = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                            String              dt1         = dfDate_day1.format(cal1.getTime());

                            bdb.insertButtonPresses(1, dt1);

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }


                    Thread timer=new Thread(){
                      public void run(){
                         try
                            {
                              sleep(30000);

                              showAlert("Its taking time to get the activated VAS Services, please wait for few seconds ...");

                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                Log.e("Show Alert Message", "********"+e);               
                            }
                       }
                    };
                    timer.start();

                    Thread timer1=new Thread(){
                          public void run(){
                             try
                                {
                                  sleep(45000);

                                  showAlert2();

                                }
                                catch(Exception e){
                                    Log.e("Show Alert Message", "********"+e);               
                                }
                           }
                        };
                        timer1.start();

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("Exception", "******Exception*****" +e);
                }
            }
         });
    }

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public void sendMessage()
    {
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("155223", null, "STOP", null, null);

            SimpleDateFormat    dfDate_day  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
            Calendar            cal         = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            String              dt          = dfDate_day.format(cal.getTime());

            bdb.insertSMS("Me","Your request to check activated services has been initiated  ",dt,0);

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager =((TelephonyManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
            String operatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();

            Vector<User> vctNumber  = bdb.getPhoneNumber();
            String mobile = "";
            for(int i = 0; i< vctNumber.size(); i++){
                User usr = (User)vctNumber.elementAt(i);
                mobile =  usr.getNumber();
                Log.v("mobile", "**********"+mobile);
            }

            bdb.insertMsg(mobile, "", "STOP", "", dt, operatorName, "155223", "", "", "", "");

    }




    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

     private void showAlert(final String error){
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
                    View al = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_timeout, null);
                    builder.setView(al);
                    alert = builder.create();
                    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                    if(MainActivity.this.isFinishing()){
                                alert.dismiss();
                    }else{
                              alert.show(); 
                     }
                }
            });
    }


     private void showAlert2(){
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
                    View al = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_timeout_second, null);
                    builder.setView(al);
                    alert = builder.create();
                    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                    Button btnOk =  (Button)al.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
                    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                        tvWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        wvPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progress = 361;
                        pw_two.stopSpinning();
                        pw_two.resetCount();
                        alert.dismiss();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "45000 Exception**********"+e);
                    }
                }
            });

            if(MainActivity.this.isFinishing()){
                alert.dismiss();
            }else{
                 alert.show();  
            }
          }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: r u doing anything on key???

Comment: no i m not doing any thing on backpress...